# If no functions included in a header file are used, does the compiler still compile this file?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, theory

Say I #include "math.h" in a simple C program while doing a math calculation so I can use the constant for PI. Then, I take out the usage of 'math.h' without actually removing the #include.  Would this irrelevant file still compile and make my program larger or will it be ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of pre-processor directive `#include` for a header file with no parseable code will not increase the size of the compiled binary.

Typically a header file will only usually include declarations - not definitions. So the inclusion of a C header file will not normally increase the size of the binary anyway.

For example - in a header file this statement `int maxlines;`
would create the definition of a variable which would be stored in the compiled binary file. The inclusion of the definition would increase the size of the binary. 
Function declarations and pre-processor tokens such as `int parseFiles(const char *file);` and `#include MAX_LINES 80` however will not increase the program size.

One effect of keeping the #include statement will be to increase the time taken to compile slightly.

Comment: Thankyou so much, you just fed my hungry curiosity